# Как из js кода в html вызвать функцию Python из QWebEngineView

Tags: python, gui, pyqt, qwebengineview, qwebchannel

Пытаюсь создать приложение с помощью *PyQt*. 
Пытаюсь из **`js`** кода в **`html`** вызвать функцию, написанную на *Python*.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так? 
При запуске приложения отображает **`html`**, но код не срабатывает. Спасибо!

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWebChannel import QWebChannel
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


class CallHandler(QObject):
    @pyqtSlot()
    def test(self):
        print('call received')


html = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>        
    <script src="qrc:///qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js"></script>
    <script>
    var backend;
    new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function (channel) {
        backend = channel.objects.backend;
    });

    document.getElementById("header").addEventListener("click", function(){
        backend.test();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body> <button id="header">Header.</button> </body>
</html>
'''


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.view = QWebEngineView()
        self.view.page().setHtml(html)
        channel = QWebChannel()
        handler = CallHandler()
        channel.registerObject('backend', handler)
        self.view.page().setWebChannel(channel)
        self.view.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWebChannel import QWebChannel
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


html = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>        
  <script src="qrc:///qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button class='btn' onclick='sentBack()'>Header.</button>

  <script>
    new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function (channel) {
      backend = channel.objects.testObject;        
    });
    
    var msg = "message from js"; 
    function sentBack(){
        backend.test(msg);
    }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
'''


class CallHandler(QObject):
    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def test(self, msg):                    
        print(f'call received: {msg}')
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testWeb = CallHandler()                       
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWeb = QWebEngineView()
    myChannel = QWebChannel()
    myWeb.page().setWebChannel(myChannel)
    myChannel.registerObject('testObject', testWeb) 
    myWeb.setHtml(html)
    myWeb.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]